# Exclude ALL posts from sub categories

Tags: posts, exclude

Need help with a wordpress-task

I want ALL the posts from sub categories to be excluded.

Example:

- Cake

  - Pie

    - Apple
    - Pear
    - Banana

If i post a post in Banana, i don't want it to show up in Pie or Cake. I just want posts that are posted in banana to show in banana, not in the top categories.

How can i do this?

I found a code for it to put in functions.php but and it does the trick with the first category, but not the second.

```
function fb_filter_child_cats($query) {
$cat = get_term_by('name', $query->query_vars['category_name'], 'category');
$child_cats = (array) get_term_children( &$cat->term_id, 'category' );
// also possible
// $child_cats = (array) get_term_children( get_cat_id($query->query_vars['category_name']), 'category' );
if ( !$query->is_admin )
$query->set( 'category__not_in', array_merge($child_cats) );
return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'fb_filter_child_cats' );
```

Comment: Could you please mark one of the answers as accepted? Or if you had any different implementation, suggest that and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3):

Don't change your template, and please do **not** use `query_posts`.

Add this to your `function.php`:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_out_children');

function filter_out_children( $query ) {
  if ( is_main_query() && is_category() && ! is_admin() ) {
     $qo = $query->get_queried_object();
     $tax_query = array(
       'taxonomy' => 'category',
       'field' => 'id',
       'terms' => $qo->term_id,
       'include_children' => false
     );
     $query->set( 'tax_query', array($tax_query) );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is by using a Category Template.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Basically you want to have a category.php page, and then change

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

to this

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); if (in_category($cat)) { ?>
```

and

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

to

```
<?php } endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test it right now, but you can try with this code:

```
$current_cat = intval( get_query_var('cat') );
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args=array(
   'category__and' => array($current_cat),
   'paged' => $paged,
   'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
query_posts($args);

?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

   Your content - here!

wp_reset_query();
```

You need to edit the template file where you want to show the posts and put this code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, it worked for me

```
<?php 

// Subcategories IDs as an array

// In this example, the parent category ID is 3
$subcategories = get_categories('child_of=3');

$subcat_array = array();
foreach ($subcategories as $subcat) {
    $subcat_array[] = '-' . $subcat->cat_ID;
}

// we also include parent category ID in the list
$subcat_array[] = '-3';

// and then call query_posts
query_posts(array('category__not_in' => $subcat_array));
```

?>

copied from

http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2009/07/13/exclude-articles-from-a-category-tree-on-your-wordpress-homepage/